# How can I find dirty git repositories across filesystem on Ubuntu 20.04? (with not commited or not pushed changes)

Tags: repository, git

Is there any tool that would

- scan my filesystem
- list git repositories where some changes are not committed
- list git repositories where some changes are not pushed to `origin` (or currently active remote) and local repository is ahead
- be usable on Ubuntu 20.04

?

(it should not be subjective as criteria listed here are objective)

Comment: You can try do some scripting starting with `find ~ -name .git -type d -execdir git status {} +` .

Comment: @N0rbert I know that I can write it on my own (though I would rather build it in Python, easier to debug) but I really hope that there is an existing tool for that.

Comment: To people voting close: can you let me know why you are doing this? I thought that it would be obviously applying to software on Ubuntu but I now specified it explicitly

Comment: Try SmartGit. Its free for own use. Available [here](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) It will scan and show you your git projects and you can see graphically the state etc, of each project.

Comment: @mike Their [licensing](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/purchase/) is weird "SmartGit can be used free of charge by Open Source developers, teachers and their students, or for hobby, non-paid usage." - OK, that describes all my projects. And they title it "Non-Commercial Licenses" what makes it confusing. OK, maybe it is intended as "Non-Commercial" for them?

Plenty of teachers and developers of open source (including me) are paid for at least part of work.

But on starting the program I have no option covering this case, only "solely for non-commercial purposes"

Comment: @mikemcleod Note that if this works then you can submit it as an answer ("solely for non-commercial purposes" would not be true for me and I have not decided yet whether I prefer to pay or create own script). Note that bounty expires soon.

Comment: There are a number of 'free' Git GUI's [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis). I looked at Vershd and it will do what you want, in fact the first step after the intro is to perform a search for repositories.

Comment: you wrote: "@N0rbert I know that I can write it on my own (though I would rather build it in Python, easier to debug)"  What did make you not do do so ?

Comment: @Luuk From bounty description: "I really hope that there is existing tool that I can use (and maybe contribute back if needed) rather than cobble together yet another fragile script."

I have already several fragile, failing/failed scripts, many relying on something deprecated or not fully working. I really prefer to avoid reinventing the wheel if possible.

Comment: It really does not matter how you use `git`, you can do it directly from the command-line as N0rbert showed, or you can use PHP, (see: https://gist.github.com/dbu/2843660 ) or you can change that to something in Python.

Comment: @Luuk This command will only list status of all git repositories, right? I am interested in listing only ones where there is something to be pushed.

Comment: You always can change `git --status` to something else to get the needed info. It's up to you to specify which info you need.